# SwiftUI TabView inside a NavigationView

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

So I know it's not really encouraged to put a TabView inside a NavigationView and that you're supposed to do it the other way around. But the way I want my app I don't really see how I can have it another way...

So I have a login screen in which a user inputs their username, then only once I verify that everything is okay with username I wanna bring them over to a TabView(the search button is a navlink) I don't really see any other way to implement this but the problem is with my implementation is once I switch tabs in the tab view, the navigation title doesn't seem to change, and there also doesn't seem to be a navigation bar because when I scroll the old NavigationTitle gets drawn over by a Text View I have.

I'm not sure if adding code would help in this case because it seems this is just kind of a problem with TabViews inside NavigationViews but if someone wants me to show some code I can add an edit with it. I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas for how I could fix something like this or some other way to implement this?
[image: Text View blocking NavigationView]

[image: Login Screen]

Edit:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink{
                TabView{
                    ScrollView{
                        Text("Some view")
                    }
                    .tabItem{
                        Text("New View")
                    }
                    ScrollView{
                        Text("Another view")
                    }
                    .tabItem{
                        Text("Another view")
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Go to new view!")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to have `TabView()` inside a `NavigationView`. Every time we switch between pages in any app, the navigating is mostly expected, so almost every view is inside the NavigtionView for this reason.

You can achieve this design with something like this (see the bottom images also):

```
struct LoginDemo: View {
  @State var username = ""
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter your user name", text: $username)
                .font(.headline)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(width: 300)
                .border(.black)
            NavigationLink {
                GotoTabView()
            } label: {
                Text("search")
            }
            .disabled(username == "Admin" ? false : true)
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Hey It's Nav View")
  }
}
struct GotoTabView: View {
  @State var temp = "status"
  @State var selection = "view1"
  var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        Image("Swift")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .tabItem {
                Text("view 1")
            }
            .tag("view1")
        Image("Swift")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
            .tabItem {
                Text("view 2")
            }
            .tag("view2")
    }
    .onChange(of: selection){ _ in
        if selection == "view1" {
            temp = "status"
        }
        else {
            temp = "hero"
        }
    }
    .toolbar{
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
            Text(temp)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

NavigationView:

[image]

TabView:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you then try to add a navigation title to the loginview and also both the tabviews does the title change for all views for you? For me the navigation title is the same no matter what tabview I go to even though I set it and the text is also getting cut off like I showed.

Comment: I added a line of code, one navigation title per view. Both showed a different navigation title. You can check my updated Images and Codes.

Comment: Yeah but what if you put a nav title on both tab views? For me they both still have the same nav title.

Comment: Do you know how TabView works? It does not navigate its child views like Navigation View, Navigation Title changes or happens because of navigation link or navigating, if you don't navigate anything, how do you expect navigation title to change? Therefore, TabView uses only one Navigation Title.

Comment: Right my bad that makes sense, so if I want some navigation like title I guess I just need to implement that myself using Text views?

Comment: @DanBriggs you are correct. Just simple HStack with Text() or up to your design.

Comment: Thanks I also included an edit, I just embedded the current view into a VStack and added a Text View up top but as you can see this isn't exactly what I want, the text view gets put below the navigation bar. How would I be able to put it on the same level as the navigation bar? Like where the navigation title would be?

Comment: But that just adds that ToolbarItem to the whole TabView does it not? I want different text for each different tab. ``TabView{
            
            
            ProfileView(vm: vm)
                .tabItem{
                    Text("Stats")
                }
                
            DailyView(vm: vm)
                .tabItem{
                    Text("Daily")
                }
            
            
        } ``That's what my code tabview looks like but when I tried to just add a toolbaritem with text in them it did nothing.

Comment: @DanBriggs I edited and added new code and images of `TabView`. Now, you will have different title for each tab. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have just one last problem which is that when I scroll the text still seems to clip through the title and the text just goes through it and it looks really ugly. It's the second picture in the original post I'm not sure what I can do to fix that.

Comment: This is why MRE is important because now I don't know what scroll you're talking about. I assumed your problem and tested some code. Make sure your ChildView layout is something like this `VStack { ScrollView { contents... } .tabItem{}.tag() }`, this layout is always under the title bar and back button, not sticking together. Make sure you tested properly with simulator not canvas inside Xcode. All my provided codes should not cause this problem because the VStack or Image is always under the nav bar.

Comment: I added an edit with some code, really just a basic MRE but when I click the NavLink, I can scroll up and it's just fine you can see there's a NavigationBar but if I click the other tab then go back to the first tab and try to scroll up again the text goes through the NavigationBar now.